# Match with blank and without blank

Tags: c#, regex

I want or get the name of mp3

I'm currently using this code

```
string str = "onClick=\"playVideo('upload/honour-3.mp3',this)\"/>  onClick=\"playVideo('upload/honor is my honor .mp3',this)\"/>  onClick=\"playVideo('upload/honour-6.mp3',this)\"/>  ";
string Pattern = @"playVideo\(\'upload\/(?<mp3>\S*).mp3\'\,this\)";

if (Regex.IsMatch(str, Pattern))
{
    MatchCollection Matches = Regex.Matches(str, Pattern);

    foreach (Match match in Matches)
    {
       string fn = match.Groups["mp3"].Value;
       Debug.Log(match.Groups["mp3"].Value);
    }
}
```

But \ S * matches only like

honour-3

honour-6

i can't get "honor is my honor "

i try the"\S*\s*",but it not work

I have a lot of how many blank string uncertain

How do I use Regex to get mp3's name?

Comment: won't `.*` do the job..If you want you can use `upload\/(?<mp3>(\S|\s)*).mp3` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have to match "playVideo" and "upload", Your regex is unnecessarily complicated. This one produces the expected results:

```
@"[\w\s-]+\.mp3"
```

Results:

```
"honour-3.mp3", 
"honor is my honor .mp3", 
"honour-6.mp3"
```

If you don't want `.mp3` at the end of the matches, you can change the regex to `@"([\w\s-]+)\.mp3"` and select the second group (the first one is the whole match).

```
Regex.Matches(str, @"([\w\s-]+)\.mp3").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Results:

```
"honour-3", 
"honor is my honor ", 
"honour-6"
```

Comment: Amazing! This works!
I refer to the Developer, still no way to understand this principle

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me so much!